# Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am currently learning Symfony and Doctrine by [reading the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html).

I don't understand the difference between **find** and **findOneById**. I tried to use them both in this simple example and it looks they do the same thing to me.

```
$product = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:ProductEntity')
                ->findOneById($id);
```

Are they really the same thing or there is some difference? And where I can find the detailed documentation for all these methods?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case, they happen to do the same thing. Looking at [this example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database), you'll notice that `find()` looks for the field named after the primary key. `findOneBy<Field>()` will explicitly use the field in the name of the method, even if it's not the primary key, and will return the first record. So, in the end, if the primary key is indeed named `id`, then both will do the same thing.

```
// query by the primary key (usually "id")
$product = $repository->find($id);

// dynamic method names to find based on a column value
$product = $repository->findOneById($id);
$product = $repository->findOneByName('foo');
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand that was a dynamic method name, that's why I had trouble finding it.

Comment: I'd like to add that `find()` looks up an entity by primary key, which could consist of multiple columns (compound key). `find()` supports this by passing an array like `array('column1' => $value1, 'column2' => $value2)`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an API [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html) I don't think there is any difference: the two methods, when call the way you call them, do this:

```
return $this->_em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityPersister($this->_entityName)->load($id);
```

But find will be quicker and far quicker in some cases, because it doesn't use the `__call` magic method, and because `find()` checks a map of the current unit of work before whereas load() doesn't (see the @todo):

```
/**                                                                         
 * Loads an entity by a list of field criteria.                             
 * ...
 * 
 * @todo Check identity map? loadById method? Try to guess whether $criteria is the id?
 */                                                                         
public function load(array $criteria, $entity = null, $assoc = null, array $hints = array(), $lockMode = 0)
```

So prefer `find()`, `findOneById()` is just a less efficient method to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, is not the same thing.

Think about it. If you call "findBy()" you assume you'll receive a collection of entities ( 0, 1 or more than one ). So, to get all results, you'll need to iterate ArrayCollection or just get first ( $result->first() ).

If your query is by a unique key ( As this case ), you can just get unique entity by calling "getOneById()" and you will receive the entity as result.

```
/**
 * Retrieving Product with 'findOneBy'
 */
$product = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:ProductEntity')
                ->findOneById($id);

/**
 * Retrieving Product with 'findBy'
 */
$product = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:ProductEntity')
                ->findById($id)
                ->first();
```

Semantically, the first one it the best.

*TIP

Entity should be called just Product.
Why? Because is under "/Entity" folder ( Almost, should... ), and namespace will contain info about "What is exactly Product"

Answer (score 2):

```
// query by the primary key (usually "id")
$product = $repository->find($id);

// dynamic method names to find based on a column value
$product = $repository->findOneById($id);
// $foo is any name which you want to find from database
$product = $repository->findOneByName($foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

It calls the same method in the end.

```
findByKey('value')
```

Is basically the same as

```
findBy(array('key' => 'value'))
```

Where key is the property of the entity and value is the value of the property.

```
findById($id)
```

Is a special case of the above. And so is

```
find($id)
```

All of these methods execute the same query in the end. However, there is a difference in

```
findBy()
```

and

```
findOneBy()
```

Where findOneBy() only returns a single result and findBy will return all the results satisfying the demands.

However, in general it is considered good practice to use DQL queries instead. Consider lazy loading, array hydration, prepared statements, etc.
This is an interesting article on the topic:
[Some Doctrine 2 Best Practices](http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/some-doctrine-2-best-practices/)

Answer (score 0):

Is the same thing, but I prefer the findOneBy method. It's more clear.