# Symfony Class "App:ConfigSystem" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

After a `composer update`, Symfony does not work properly for me. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the project and composer several times. I was able to narrow down my current problem a bit.

In my project we currently use this notation:

```
$config = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("App:ConfigSystem")->find(1);
```

Now, Symfony complains that it can't find the class `App:ConfigSystem` anymore.

[image: Error Message Symfony]

Once I change the code to the following:

```
$config = $this->em->getRepository(ConfigSystem::class)->find(1)
```

everything runs normally again. Since we still use the first notation more often in the project, I wanted to ask you if you know the problem and how to fix it again. Unfortunately, I have found nothing in this direction.

`composer update`, etc. has unfortunately not helped.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this functionality was removed in Doctrine ORM 3: https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine/issues/69#issuecomment-541446086

Comment: What version did you update from and to?  The colon notation is on it's way out but just doing an update really should not have broken things.

Comment: @Justinas I'm struggling to understand your logic for closing.  Yes at some point the colon logic will be removed.  No when knows when.  ORM 3 has been under development for many years.  The question itself just involves an update which should not have broken anything.  Why close it for something that might eventually happen sometime in the future?  I'm thinking the problem might be similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72625905/symfony-4-4-annotationdriver/72627654#comment128305311_72627654

Comment: No Cerad, you just have to look at the official Symfony documentation (link [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database)) to see that it is the `ConfigSystem::class` notation that is recommended since Symfony 4 .3 minimum. So I'm agree with @Justinas to close the issue. The only solution is to replace the calls to the repositories with the way that works and that is recommended. You should always favour the doc and be up to date rather than your  own crafts!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony/Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936331/symfony-doctrine)

Comment: @vinceAmstoutz Thanks for the links but there is an important distinction between standard practices and non-working practices.  The alias approach still works just fine even in the latest 6.1.  Changing a bunch of aliases to class names might actually involve quite a bit of work.  And it might not even solve this particular issue.  Even the posted error image did not show the full error message.  If the OP ever responds and provides more info then I suspect the problem could be solved.

Comment: The question was closed just as I was writing the answer.  Basically upgrading doctrine/orm to 2.12 broke a bunch of stuff.  Not just for 4.4 but 5.0,5.1,5.2 and 5.3 as well.  Downgrading to 2.11 fixes the alias issue as well as a bunch of other stuff.  More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72625905/symfony-4-4-annotationdriver/72627654#comment128305311_72627654  I will say that the notion that this question is not about programming is quite bizarre.

Comment: Hello,
thank you very much for all the answers. We have now changed our project and have replaced all alias references. Unfortunately, we have not managed to fix the error by downgrade or otherwise.