# Issue with Doctrine namespace aliases during upgrade from Symfony 3 to 4

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to upgrade a Symfony 3 application to Symfony 4, but I am having trouble with Doctrine's namespace aliases. My entities are located under `AppBundle\Entity` (as was the default in older Symfony versions) and there was an alias for that, so my entities are referred to via `AppBundle:SomeEntity` all over my codebase. I understand that the new way to do this is to use the FQCN instead, but I would like to avoid having to do a massive find&replace operation right now.

I modified `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` with the following mapping:

```
mappings:
    AppBundle:
        is_bundle: false
        type: annotation
        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/AppBundle/Entity'
        prefix: 'AppBundle\Entity'
        alias: AppBundle
```

However, I only get a `ReflectionException` saying `Class AppBundle:SomeEntity does not exist`. As far as I can tell from the stack trace, the alias is never resolved, just passed directly down to `AbstractManagerRegistry` as a class name, which then just passes it to the `ReflectionClass` constructor. The calling code, e.g., looks like this (inside a controller): `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:SomeEntity")->...`

I have now idea what the problem is. It looks like there is just no logic that would resolve aliases in this code path. It is probably a configuration issue. However, the configuration is mostly the default that comes with Symfony 4. I basically just replaced "App" with "AppBundle". Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: The most recent versions of [4.4 broke the Doctrine alias system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72736548/symfony-class-appconfigsystem-does-not-exist#comment128500764_72736548) as well as a few other Doctrine related things.  You need to set Doctrine ORM versionto 2.11.  It is still a complete mystery (to me) why Symfony did this.  5.4 and 6.x all work just fine.  It's just 4.4 that is impacted.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you so much! That was it. I downgraded to 2.11 and now it works as expected. I had to remove the migrations bundle, though, in order to satisfy all dependency constraints, but I don't use it anyway, so no problem there.